# Excel: Group 1700 entries by the year in which they each occurred in

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a list of all crime that occurred in a neighborhood from 2014 to present day. Each incident-entry (it's own separate row) has a date value (making a date column), which I can format to just be the year easily enough. What I'm having trouble with is creating some kind of chart that shows how many crimes were reported each year--2014, 2015, 2016, all the way to 2022, as a means of ascertaining whether crime is on the rise.

How might I do this?

Comment: A pivot table is useful for this. From your data, you can generate a (pivot) chart with a more concise view of what you want to show.

Comment: Welcome! Here's what Microsoft says about [**PivotChart**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivotchart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c)